# Is it possible to query by list in Hive?

Tags: python, sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have a list of ids

```
[id1, id2, id3.......]
```

I would like to query all the rows such that ids match one of the id in the list

Right now I am doing it in a hacky way

```
# This is a python script
id_list_str = "`_id` = '" + str(_id[0]) + "' "

for m_id in _id[1:]:
    id_list_str += " OR `_id` = '" + str(m_txn_id) + "' "


hive_query = "SELECT" \
             "  `_id`, " \
             "  time, " \
             "  state " \
             "FROM " \
             "  transaction " \
             "WHERE " \
             "  %s " \
             % (id_list_str)
```

I don't think this scales as the number of id in my list increase, is there another way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `in` clause, such as in this example:

`select * from table_name where column_name in ('medicine','physics','biology')`

Answer (score 1):

In hive try a lateral view explode to expand the list.  This will work if you have many lists as well.

```
  select a.id
    , a.time
    , a.state
  from transaction a 
 left semi join
  (SELECT distinct id 
  from list_of_ids LATERAL VIEW explode(id_list_Str) idTable as id
  ) 
  t on a.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Hive version are you using? 
Hive 0.13 now do support IN/EXISTS in the WHERE-clause .. The issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-784